# $ is not a function/pickadate is not a function

Tags: reactjs, materialize

Checked all same questions, neither of them didn't help me or I'm missing something. Would be great if someone could help me with that

I'm using react, project created by create-react-app without ejecting.

In index.html I tried to import jquery and materialize scripts to use datepicker:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

.
    In one of my components i have an *input* and function *componentDidMount()*

```
<input className="col s2 input-field datepicker"
                  id="dateInput"
                  type="text"
                  ref="date"/>
```

componentDidMount() ->

```
componentDidMount() {
    //tried $('.datepicker') as well
    $('#dateInput').pickadate({
            selectMonths: true,
            selectYears: 15,
            today: 'Today',
            clear: 'Clear',
            close: 'Ok',
            closeOnSelect: false
        });
}
```

In this case I get error $ is not defined

```
componentDidMount() {
    document.getElementById('').pickadate({
            selectMonths: true,
            selectYears: 15,
            today: 'Today',
            clear: 'Clear',
            close: 'Ok',
            closeOnSelect: false
        });
}
```

In this case I get error .pickadate({..}) is not a function

Comment: `pickadate` is not a core jquery widget. Make sure to include that lib too.

Comment: 1. Include pickdate lib
2. $ is not defined => declare var $: any;

Comment: if it's included in index.html then why i should declare/import $ and how do I include pickadate. Unfortunately, I didn't find how to import it and how it works